# How do I create a chart in Visual Studio Windows Form whose minimum and maximum values are not numbers but strings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create charts in Visual Studio 2015 Windows Forms Application that will chart the data from a sensor and display each point with the time it was received in the x-axis. I have created a simplified version of what I attempting in the following code. Here I am tracking generic points and placing strings in the x-axis. My problem is that **I don't want my initial point or maximum point to be zero but instead the first and last string of my vector (vec) respectively.**

[image: This image shows the graph my code generates.].

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    string[] vec = new string[7]  
    { "11:00", "12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00" };
    int i = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int f = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        if (f == 2)
        {
            f = 0;
        }
        if (f == 0)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        if (f == 1)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        f++;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(vec[i], (2 * i));
        i = i + (n * 1);
        if (i == vec.Length)
        {
            n = -1;
            i = 5;
        }
        if (i==0)
        {
            n = 1;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: strings __are__ not values. Never add x-values as strings if you ever want to do anything with those values. It just makes no sense at all!

Comment: I need to use strings in order to display a time of day (such as 11:00 am) along the x-axis (see picture), How else can I display such information? My plan is to retrieve the "time of day" values (hours, minutes, seconds, etc,) from my computer as integers and convert them to strings (.ToStrings() command) and then display said strings along the x-axis. I just need to know how to write to the minimum and maximum values of the x-axis.

Comment: _How else can I display such information?_ By using DateTimes and a suitable Format string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** use strings for x-values, unless they are actually **meaningless**, like city or person names.

`Strings` are **copied** to the axis-labels but otherwise converted to `doubles` coming out as `0s` (!!); this means you can't **use** them for **anything**.

But you may want to use them for:

- formatting (you need that)
- setting display ranges (you want that, too)
- setting zoom ranges
- tooltips
- calculations
- expressions
- etc..

So you should add them **either** as numbers **or** as `DateTimes`. Here is an example and the result:

```
Series s = chart.Series[0];
// string[] vec = new string[7] 
// { "11:00", "12:00", "1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00" };
TimeSpan[] tvec = new TimeSpan[7] 
          { new TimeSpan( 11, 0, 0), new TimeSpan( 12, 0, 0), new TimeSpan( 13, 0, 0),
            new TimeSpan( 14, 0, 0) ,new TimeSpan( 15, 0, 0) ,new TimeSpan( 16, 0, 0),
            new TimeSpan( 17, 0, 0)  };

DateTime d0 = new DateTime(0);

foreach (var t in tvec)
    s.Points.AddXY(d0.Add(t), t.Hours);

ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "h:mm";

ca.AxisX.Minimum = d0.Add(tvec.First()).ToOADate();
ca.AxisX.Maximum = d0.Add(tvec.Last()).ToOADate();
```

[image]

A few further notes:

- Do take note of the special conversion function [`ToOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the complementary [`FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!
- To **create** the `TimeSpans` we need to use the `24h` format.
- You can display the times as in the `24h` format by using the "H:mm" format string.
- I would use a `List<Tmespan>` and fill it in a loop or even with LINQ:

---

```
 List<TimeSpan> tvec = Enumerable.Range(11, 7).Select(x => new TimeSpan(x, 0, 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me a lot.

Comment: Good to hear. - If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I just wanted to know if I could increase the length of a timespan list without specifying a range?

Comment: what would that mean ? you can add or insert  anything to the list or use a variable to specify the number of items.